# How can I install netbook edition without losing Windows?

Tags: 10.10, ubuntu-netbook, wubi, windows-7

I'm using Windows 7 Starter on my netbook and I want to install Ubuntu 10.10 netbook edition but I don't want to lose anything. I want to keep Windows and use both systems on my netbook.

I created a Ubuntu USB stick, and restarted to install but there isn't an "alongside other operating system" option. What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

Check this out http://lifehacker.com/5403100/dual+boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-in-perfect-harmony

Also, I think you could try the ubuntu-desktop image, install it and then in Ubuntu install unity package (the netbook-edition environment).

Answer (score 1):

I find the nicest way to install Ubuntu on a netbook without risk of losing windows is to use Wubi. http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/windows-installer